# Running Flyway migrations on gradle refresh

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx, flyway

I am still trying to wrap my head around gradle so please bear with me.

I'm trying to set up flyway migrations to run automatically on every gradle refresh/build instead of having to run a command-line command. So when someone is pulling the latest changes including some new migrations their local db will be up to date.

I have this build.grade in the root dir:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
}

allprojects {
    ...
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"

    dependencies {
        compile project(":shared")
    }
}

project(":server") {
    apply plugin: "java"

    dependencies {
        compile project(":shared")
    }
}

project(":shared") {
    apply plugin: "java"
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

Where I've tried merging the lines from the flyway get started pages.

I basically want to run the `$ gradle flywayMigrate -i` command from within the build.gradle file. I've tried with `build.finalizedBy(flywayMigrate)` but to no avail.

How would I do something like that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to make `build` finalized by `flywayMigrate` you need to run `gradle build` which probably You didn't.

To run `flywayMigrate` you can use [`defaultTasks`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#defaultTasks(java.lang.String...)) which will run the tasks configured if no other are provided. So:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.191'
    }
}

plugins {
    id "org.flywaydb.flyway" version "4.1.2"
}

flyway {
    url = 'jdbc:h2:file:./target/foobar'
    user = 'sa'
}

defaultTasks 'flywayMigrate'
```

When it comes to configuring `-i` (logging level) from within `build.gradle` it seems to be impossible with the newest gradle versions.

Comment: adding a line `println(getDefaultTasks())` shows that there are no default tasks, but when adding the defaultTasks it shows the flywayMigrate in the list.

Comment: That's expected behaviour. Then you need just to run `gradle` and migrations will be run. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Running a program the IDE says "gradle build" but the command hasn't run.  

In IntelliJ I can rightclick a task in the gradle view and press "execute after build". That makes the task run every time I run the program but that change is of course only local.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: If you run `gradle build` (or any other task) migrations won't run since if any task is passed `defaultTasks` are ignored. You can both configure `defaultTasks` and `build.dependsOn flywayMigrate`. If you find my answer useful please upvote it at least ;)

Comment: What I want is actually to avoid using the commandline and have the task run when running the program.

Comment: Ok, so I suggest you to add `defaultTasks` - it will run migrations if just gradle was run, and define dependencies on `build` (or any other required task). Unfortunately it can't be configured in a single place.

Comment: Thank you @Opal , what I was looking for was a variation of what you said: `bootRun { dependsOn = 'flywayMigrate' } }`